# smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected python 3 send mail error

Tags: python, email, ssl, smtplib

im tryna send email with yahoo.com server but it fails for some reason

can anyone please help me, i have no idea what to do

i tried send it with gmail but got even worse error message.

i know here is issue with *SMTP.login()* method but i cant solve it

any solutions?

this is my code:

```
import smtplib, ssl

sender = '******@yahoo.com'
receiver = sender
password = '******'
msg = 'just a test'  
port = 587


with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.yahoo.com', port) as server:
    server.connect('smtp.mail.yahoo.com', port)
    server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.ehlo()
    print('connected')
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(sender, password)
    print('logged in')
    server.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg)
    print('sent')
```

i got this error:

```
send: 'ehlo [192.168.1.8]\r\n'
connected
reply: b'250-hermes--canary-production-ir2-f74ffc99c-2vqg6 Hello [192.168.1.8] 
[194.44.96.40])\r\n'
reply: b'250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: b'250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: b'250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250-SIZE 41697280\r\n'
reply: b'250 STARTTLS\r\n' 
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'hermes--canary-production-ir2-f74ffc99c-2vqg6 Hello [192.168.1.8] 
[194.44.96.40])\nPIPELINING\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\n8BITMIME\nSIZE 41697280\nSTARTTLS'
send: 'STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: b'220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS\r\n'
reply: retcode (220); Msg: b'2.0.0 Ready to start TLS'
send: 'ehlo [192.168.1.8]\r\n'
connection established
reply: b'250-hermes--canary-production-ir2-f74ffc99c-2vqg6 Hello [192.168.1.8]    
[194.44.96.40])\r\n'
reply: b'250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: b'250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: b'250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250-SIZE 41697280\r\n'
reply: b'250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN XOAUTH2 OAUTHBEARER\r\n' 
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'hermes--canary-production-ir2-f74ffc99c-2vqg6 Hello [192.168.1.8] 
[194.44.96.40])\nPIPELINING\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\n8BITMIME\nSIZE 41697280\nAUTH PLAIN LOGIN 
XOAUTH2 OAUTHBEARER'
send: 'AUTH PLAIN AGlib2pjdWtAeWFob28uY29tAGZhNDY1NTQxLg==\r\n'
reply: b'535 5.7.0 (#AUTH005) Too many bad auth attempts.\r\n'
reply: retcode (535); Msg: b'5.7.0 (#AUTH005) Too many bad auth attempts.'
send: 'AUTH LOGIN aWJvamN1a0B5YWhvby5jb20=\r\n'
send: 'QUIT\r\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\project1\mail_client.py", line 18, in <module>
    server.login(sender, password)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 739, in 
login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 642, in 
auth
    (code, resp) = self.docmd("AUTH", mechanism + " " + response)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 432, in 
docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 405, in 
getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Comment: There is an option in the mail account settings for both yahoo and gmail to allow app connections like this. Have you enabled it? https://www.saleshandy.com/smtp/yahoo-smtp-settings/

Comment: And as an aside, you may want to change the password on that account, if you have pasted a live log file above, as it is easy to extract the password from it. ;)

Comment: `'535 5.7.0 (#AUTH005) Too many bad auth attempts.\r\n'` looks to be the reason.  You may have to wait for a while before trying again, or log into your account via the web and check that nothing needs resetting.